# Navbar drop-down menu not working with Angular and Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

I'm developing a web application with Angular 5 and Bootstrap 4 and I'm having problems with the nav menu bar dropdowns. I'm following the documentation https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/ but I don't know why drop-down menu doesn't work!

```
<header>
    <div class = "row align-items-end nopadding">
        <div class = "col-md-3" style = "background-color: blanchedalmond"><app-logo></app-logo></div>
        <div class = "col-md-6">
            <ul class="nav justify-content-center">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link menu-item" href="#">Ligas</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link menu-item" href="#">Gráficas</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link menu-item" href="#">Artículos</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link menu-item dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Clasificaciones</a>      
                    <div class=" dropdown dropdown-menu">
                        <a class="dropdown-item menu-item" href="#">Equipos</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item menu-item" href="#">Jugadoras</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
                    </div>
                </li>                
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class = "col-md-3 right-content">
            Right column
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit I:**

I have added jquery and popper through npm, update muy angular-cli.json and restart the server:

**angular-cli.json:**

[image]

And when I load the page I've got this error:

```
Error in the source mapping: request failed with status 404 
Resource URL: http://localhost:4200/ scripts.bundle.js 
Sourcemap URL: bootstrap.min.js.map
```

When I have installed jquery I've got this output:

[image]

And when I hace installed popper I've got this output:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It works for me. Have you been able to repro the issue in JSfiddle or the like?

Comment: It works if you don't use Angular 5, with Angular 5 it doesn't work. Have you tested the code with Angular 5 inside a header component, for example?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You have to make sure that `popper.js` is included and loaded in your Angular app because that is required for all things that pop up or drop down in Bootstrap 4.

Here's what the relevant part of your `angular-cli.json` should look like:

```
"styles": [
"../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
"styles.css"
],
"scripts": [
"../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
"../node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
"../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
],
```

To install popper.js use this command:

`npm install popper.js --save`

Reference: https://www.npmjs.com/package/popper.js

Comment: I've included bootstrap in my angular-cli.json. Where is popper,js?

Comment: That should normally be loaded immediately before bootstrap.min.js Look at the angular-cli.json in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48362985/8270343

Comment: It looks like you've installed popper but not `popper.js`. I don't know what the contents of that `index.js` in your popper folder are but those contents probably aren't **popper.js**.

Comment: Inside popper folder I haven't a popper.js folder :(

Comment: `npm install popper.js --save` is what you need: https://www.npmjs.com/package/popper.js

Comment: Ok!!! I have installed with npm install --save popper. I'll try to install again!!!

Comment: It works!!! I think I'm gonna cry!!! :) Thank you so much for your appreciated help!!!

Comment: Congratulations! :-)

Comment: Mr. WebDevBooster. I faced dropdown issue. because i used 
"./node_modules/popper.js/dist/popper.min.js".. But correct path is 
/node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js.
thank you very much. your answer helped me to solve to issue

Comment: 10/10 worked just had to remove the `../` as it couldnt find the directory

Comment: It's not working for me even after including all the 3 js paths into the scripts array :(

Comment: **Note**: Ensure that jQuery's reference is before bootstrap.js.

Comment: I was working with angular cli and running this worked for me `ng add angular-popper`

Comment: This solution seems not to work now. any idea why?

Comment: This answer is slightly outdated, but this works: https://dev.to/myolisi/how-to-add-bootstrap-5-to-your-angular-11-project-1am2

Comment: In my case, <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a> changing data-toggle to data-bs-toggle started working fine. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 16):

I'm not allowed to add a comment to WebDevBooster's answer, so I posted a new one.
The next declaration in angular.json (angular-cli.json) will be enough:

```
"scripts": [
          "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        ]
```

The propper.js has already been included in bootstrap.bundle.min.js: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/dropdowns/#overview

Comment: bootstrap.bundle.min.js is a tricky one. I didn't realize that. Thanks.

Comment: This seems not work currently. Any ideas why?

Comment: This is good, but what if someone wants a lighter version of bootstrap

Comment: I have been struggling to get the dropdown for quite some time, and almost decided to look for alternatives, I have all the necessary dependencies popperjs, jquery, but still, it doesn't work until I set bootsrap.bundle.mi.js. This happens to be a robust way to fix the issue.

Answer (score 4):

In my case the issue was that i wasn't using angular specific attributes.
See : https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/dropdown/examples

`ngbDropdown` `ngbDropdownToggle` `ngbDropdownMenu` and `ngbDropdownItem`

I had to change

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarScrollingDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Link
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarScrollingDropdown">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
```

to:

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown" ngbDropdown>
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarScrollingDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" ngbDropdownToggle>
              Link
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu"  ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="navbarScrollingDropdown">
              <li ngbDropdownItem><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li ngbDropdownItem><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li ngbDropdownItem><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
              <li ngbDropdownItem><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
```

Comment: This look like it's the most Angular way to do this.

Comment: becareful, this code is for bootstrap 5 not 4. data-bs-toggle is BS 5. data-toggle is BS 4.

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same problem and resolved it by :

1. **npm install bootstrap --save**
2. Added the below line in **styles.css**

```html
@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
```

3. Added the below lines in the **index.html**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
```

......................

Answer (score 3):

## make sure you have installed jquery in your root folder

if not then install using NPM ---> npm install jquery --save

> Note: If you want to use bootstrap in your application, or if you already have in your project, make sure to include jQuery before including the bootstrap JavaScript file. Bootstrap’s JavaScript file requires jQuery
>
> go to the angular.json file at the root of your Angular CLI project folder, and find the scripts: [ ] property, and include the path to jQuery as follows:

```
"scripts": [ "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
       ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of adding popper, jquery dependency in your scripts, try this instead you can install ng-bootstrap (look for documentation in https://ng-bootstrap.github.io).
Advantage of using ng-bootstrap over adding scripts of bootstrap, jquery and popper
is it will not bloatup your bundle size and for these reason angular community has created ng-bootstrap.
Steps to install:

1. `npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap`
2. Once installed you need to import our main module.

Comment: This is a problem if you are already using a different component library like primeng but also want to use bootstrap nav library.

Comment: I really had a lot of trouble making this dropdown work until i removed bootstrap with npm from my angular project and then reinstalled it via ng-bootstrap. The component's templates markup needed minor edits in order to translate some bootstrap classes into ng directives, then it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick way to fix this issue.

Don't need to install `popper` or `jquery` vis `npm`, simply paste below lines in your `index.html` file inside `head tag`

```
  <!-- BootStrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- JQuery -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Popper --> 
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <!-- BootStrap JS -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Full working code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Some Website</title>
  <base href="./"> 
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  
  <!-- BootStrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- JQuery -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Popper --> 
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
 <!-- BootStrap JS -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 

</head>
<body>
  <div class="dropdown show">
  <a class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown link
  </a>

  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Additional to **`app.module.ts`**, you need to import the module `MDBBootstrapModule.forRoot()` in the module where you are putting navbar code.

**Example:** **`../custom.module.ts`**

```
import { MDBBootstrapModule } from 'angular-bootstrap-md';
...
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MDBBootstrapModule.forRoot()
  ],
...
```

Answer (score 1):

As of 21/05/2021, bootstrap 5.0.1 version has been rolled out and that seemed to have caused the issue for me. I switched back to 4.6.0 and things were good again.

**NOTE:** If you are referencing below scripts & styles in your `angular.json`, you should be fine. `bootstrap.bundle.min.js` already has `popper.js` bundled with it.

```
"styles": [
  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
  "src/styles.scss"
 ],
 "scripts": [
   "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
   "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, the fix for me was changing the data-toggle, in your case, from:

```
<a class="nav-link menu-item dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Clasificaciones</a>
```

To:

```
<a class="nav-link menu-item dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Clasificaciones</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem but I manage to find the solution, if you have bootstrap on your project the simple solution is change

```
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1
        <span class="caret"></span></a>
```

to

```
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href='target="_self"'>Page 1
        <span class="caret"></span></a>
```

in short change `href="#"` to `href='target="_self"'`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly install using command line :
npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap

add this :
"./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
in the angular.json file inside **styles** array

lastly,in the **app.module.ts** file
import dropdown module
**import { BsDropdownModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/dropdown';**
and then add the module in the "import" section as : **BsDropdownModule.forRoot()**

[image: add the BsDropdownModule.forRoot() in the import section in app.module.ts]

Answer (score 0):

### UPDATE

popperjs version has been deprecated

> You can find the new Popper v2 at @popperjs/core, this package is
> dedicated to the legacy v1

Now add these below scripts in angular.json > projects..architect.build.options.scripts

```
"scripts": [
              "node_modules/@popperjs/core/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
           ]
```

Comment: that does not work when you use bs 4. it will still try to get the old version and fail to recognize the @popperjs/core version. @popperjs/core is only working with bs 5.

Answer (score -2):

What worked for was to

1. Add this to my angular.json

```js
"scripts": [
              "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "./node_modules/popper.js/dist/popper.min.js",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ]
```

2. Add this to the header tag of the index.html

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Atwg2Pkwv9vp0ygtn1JAojH0nYbwNJLPhwyoVbhoPwBhjQPR5VtM2+xf0Uwh9KtT" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: This is a terrible solution. First you add the dependencies into your node_modules and include them in your angular.json and then you add popper and bootstrap using external links. This is complety useless and a terrible solution! Either do 1 or the other!