# Bootstrap 4 dropdown not working with Angular 12

Tags: javascript, angular, bootstrap-4

I have a sample Angular 12 project with Bootstrap 4. Everything is working in my project except the dropdown.

This SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49055721/navbar-drop-down-menu-not-working-with-angular-and-bootstrap-4/49055813) was not working for me.

I have installed jQuery, Popper and Bootstrap in my project using the NPM commands given :

```
npm install --save @popperjs/core
npm install --save bootstrap
npm install --save jquery
```

I also referred them from the angular.json :

```
"styles": [
     "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
     "src/styles.css"
],
"scripts": [
     "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
     "node_modules/@popperjs/core/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
     "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
]
```

I'm getting no error and also dropdown button is coming. But the issue is that the list is not popping up as soon as I clicked.

The sample code is given below that I took from [Bootstrap Dropdown Official Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/) for testing.

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Am I missing something which need to be added ?

Comment: When I run `npm install --save bootstrap` it installs `Bootstrap 5` so the sample code for the dropdown button supplied above won't work. Try the following code for the [dropdown button](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/dropdowns/#single-button)

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zaqsh6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html here is your working example @AnishB.

Answer (score 5):

it worked for me

```
"scripts": [
     "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js", 
     "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
]
```

**Edit :** omg. this issue was very tiring for me. i worked on it for a few hours. and the problem was solved in an unnoticed way and i don't understand the cause. i had to read bootstrap.js for [this](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/main/dist/js/bootstrap.js#L950) lol. just change the expression `data-toggle="dropdown"` to `data-bs-toggle="dropdown"` in the html file.

so :

**in html**

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note:** The `angular.json` example i shared above is still running.

Comment: Let me try this.

Comment: nothing seems wrong. did you restart the application with "ng serve" after refreshing the script sequence?

Comment: Yes ! restarted everything. Still no success. Did you try with Angular 12 ?

Comment: i am using angular 11. i am going to open a new project and try it

Comment: Did you get any success ?

Comment: i updated the comment and yes it solved the problem

Comment: Still not working for me, When I click on dropdown it does not add show class as I can see in the inspector on bootstrap site, tried copying examples from bootstrap site as well, no errors, also tried using cdn way in html to import bootstrap.bundle just in case but still nothing, strange, totally stuck.

Comment: solved, bootstrap bundle was imported twice by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Yep solution worked for me thanks!

However I didn't update angular.json as per above, instead added the bootstrap dropdown module  in app.module.ts i.e:

```
import { BsDropdownModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/dropdown';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    .....
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
    ,BsDropdownModule.forRoot()
    ...
  ]
  ,bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```