# How to add a dropdown menu with Bootstrap and Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

I just want to add a dropdown menu to my app and i noticed when i click the menu not display.
I tried some solution but nothing is working.

Here in my angular.json

```
         "styles": [
          "src/styles.css",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js",
          "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        ]
```

Is someone know what i'm missing ?
Thanks :)

Comment: can you give us the html/angular code that isn't working?

Comment: Just solved by myself, by just add this "scripts": [
          "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        ]

Thanks to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49055721/navbar-drop-down-menu-not-working-with-angular-and-bootstrap-4#:~:text=You%20have%20to%20make%20sure,drop%20down%20in%20Bootstrap%204.&text=Note%3A%20Ensure%20that%20jQuery's%20reference,js.

Answer (score 0):

Typically this will get downvoted because you haven't tried anything or given us any code from what you have tried. But I will write a basic dropdown menu for you to get started on:

HTML:

```
 <div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" *ngFor="let item of menuItems" [href]="item.url">{{item.label}}</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Angular:

```
export class YourComponent {
  menuItems = [
    {label: 'Action', url: '#'},
    {label: 'Another action', url: '#'},
    {label: 'Something else here', url: '#'}
  ];
}
```

This will give you a basic working dropdown in Angular that you can play with and work on! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks but my problem was from the import script. And It look like solved now.
Anyways tomorrow i'm gonna test you're code. Thanks vm.